# A method that could return a Child Object from a Parent Array?

Tags: java, arrays, class, parent

I'm looking for a method that could return a Child Object from a Parent Array - this means how can I make a method return a child object?

The problem is that i have this method to return a Parent Object form the array
but in the program i need a Child Object with its own attributes and the array have 3 different
type of Child Object

This is what I have so far:

```
class Store {
    private BookParents store[];
    private int ind, max;

    public Store() {
         ind=0; //Begin 0 and change with the method AddBooks;
         max=100;
         store = new BookParents[100];
    } 
public String AddBooks(BooksChild1 a){
    if(ind<max){
        store[ind++]=a;
        return "TheBooksChild added correctly";
    }
      return "Full store";
    }
public String AddBooks(BooksChild2 b){
    if(ind<max){
        store[ind++]=b;
        return "TheBooksChild added correctly";
    }
      return "Full store";
    }
public String AddBooks(BooksChild3 c){
    if(ind<max){
        store[ind++]=c;
        return "TheBooksChild added correctly";
    }
      return "Full store";
    }

    public BooksParents SearchBook(String c) {
        AnyBookChild null1 = new Book1("Unknown", 0,"Unknown","Unknown","Unknown","Unknown","Unknown");

        if(ind!=0){
            for(int i=0 ;i<ind;i++){                    
                if(c.compareTo(store[i].getName(store[i]) )==0)
                    System.out.println(store[i].PrintlnBook());                            
                    return store[i]; 
            }
            System.out.println("Book didn't find, try another name.");
            return null;
         } else {
             System.out.println("There is not books in the store");
             return null;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have multiple classes of BooksChild you will need a BookParents class that the BooksChild classes extend.  You can use still use an array of BookParents:

`store = new BookParents[100];`

Inside of each BooksChild you will use a constructor that looks something like this:

```
public class BooksChild1 extends BookParents{
     String myISBN, myTitle, myAuthor;

     public BooksChild1(String isbn, String title, String author){ 
         super(1, isbn, title, author); //1 denotes the class type 
     } 
 }
```

Inside of the BookParents class you will have another constructor:

```
public class BookParents{
     int myType;
     String myISBN, myTitle, myAuthor;

     public BookParents(int type, String isbn, String title, String author){ 
         //when a new BooksChild1 is created, it will set the myType equal to 1
         myType   = type; 
         myISBN   = isbn;
         myTitle  = title;
         myAuthor = author; 
    }

    //this accessor will allow you to find the type of BooksChild 
    public int getMyType(){ 
        return myType;
    }
}
```

`

Now for the store portion, adding a BooksChild to the array of BooksParent:

```
public class Store{
    //these declarations must be public if you want to use them in a public methods
    public BookParents store[];
    public int ind, max;

    public Store() {
        ind=0; //Begin 0 and change with the method AddBooks;
        max=100;
        store = new BookParents[100];
    }

    public String addBook(BookParnets bp){
        /*must be max-1 or otherwise it will try 
          to push a final ind of 100 which is out of bounds*/
        if(ind<max-1){ 
           store[ind++]=bp;
           return "TheBooksChild added correctly";
        }
        return "Full store";
    }
}
```

The final part will exist in your driver class when you declare BooksChild type objects to insert into your store the declaration statement for a BooksChild1 will be as follows:

```
BookParents b = new BooksChild1("isbn", "title", "author");
```

If you ever need to find the type of a BooksChild in your store array, you can use the following to return the type (let store[0] contain a BooksChild of an unknown type):

```
 store[0].getMyType();
```

Comment: But there is 3 diferent BookChild classes on the same array how could i difference any of them?